# CGContextDrawImage error in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I recently updated to Xcode 6.1 and have been working through fixing some bugs that have arisen. One issue I noticed was that my current code for setting the image of CGContextDrawImage no longer works.

This is my current code:

```
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFillOver"))
```

I just get the error:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type
```

I've tried a few things and did some searching but I haven't found any solution to what to change for 6.1. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter to `CGContextDrawImage` is a `CGImageRef!`. So use:

```
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, UIImage(named: "RadialProgressFillOver")?.CGImage)
```

Unfortunately, some of these warnings can be misleading, so you may have to go through each of the parameters, one by one, and carefully check both the type and optionality very carefully.